# How to avoid getting banned while scraping Google Play reviews?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, google-play

I'm using the following node.js google-play-scraper repository: https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper

I'm getting banned after scraping around 1500 reviews. I'm using the script similar to how it is shown in the examples:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.reviews({
  appId: 'com.mojang.minecraftpe',
  page: 0,
  sort: gplay.sort.RATING
}).then(function(apps){
  console.log('Retrieved ' + apps.length + ' reviews!');
}).catch(function(e){
  console.log('There was an error fetching the reviews!');
});
```

Recently, there has been throttling implemented, in order to avoid to hit hit Google Play's throttling limit. However, I wasn't able to figure out how to use this in my example. The throttling example provided is for gplay.search():

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

// the following method will perform batches of 10 requests per second
gplay.search({term: 'panda', throttle: 10}).then(console.log);
```

Is there a way to use throttling for gplay.reviews()?

Answer (score 0):

https://still-plateau-10039.herokuapp.com/reviews?id=mytown.preschool

id={google-app-id}

The service will return all the reviews on the app

Or simple host this locally
Source code of the service can be found at https://github.com/tohir87/googleplay-reviews